# pdf table to excel in Automation anywhere

Tags: pdf, automation, automationanywhere

I am trying to get PDF tables in excel for further processing in Automation anywhere.I tried it like converting PDF to text and then to excel but it not working as required.
Please suggest if anyone did this.

Comment: You could read about OCR(Optical character recognition) and try to look for library that would support such thing. Maybe there is a library that is able to recognize tables :-) Here you can check out the `pytesseract` lib: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Comment: I am able to recognize table and put it to text file but i need it in excel as table so that i can work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all who replied and tried to help.
But, i got the solution as there is bot already for this in botstore of AA and we can use it.
We can use this metabot and logic to perform action.
PFB link for the same:
https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/pdf-to-excel/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use OCR inbuild tool or PDF read tools and take those data items into the variables. And then try to use keystrokes (or other) to add those variables as text in textfile. As well as add those items to the excel sheet. try it.